# What are some examples of surnames written with hentaigana?

Tags: hentaigana

What are some examples of surnames written with 変体がな? Are there any common or famous surnames with 変体仮名?

Comment: What do you mean by 変体仮名? You mean the variants to ひらがな in their form illegible to most Japanese or the corresponding kanji? [This](http://codh.rois.ac.jp/char-shape/hentaigana/) shows both. If you mean the former, I doubt there existed any surname ever with  変体仮名.

Comment: I do mean 変体仮名. Seeing as there are surnames with 仮名, and the distinction between 変体仮名 and other 仮名 is little more than 120 years old, why wouldn't there be surnames with 変体仮名?

Comment: [Surnames containing hiragana are extremely rare](https://okwave.jp/qa/q3050838.html). Most probably you mistook pennames or nicknames for real. All-hiragana (real) surname is almost unimaginable. So the answer to the second question is no.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than surnames, 変体仮名 were frequently used in names (specially female names). Before 1948 there were a lot of women with 変体仮名 in their registered names. After that it seems that the law for naming a child changed and nowadays you can only use the registered かな and 漢字.

In this website you can take a look at a lot of registered 変体仮名 that were used before.
https://www.benricho.org/kana/a.html

About a specific 変体仮名 in a name, they are difficult to find but here is an example.

[image: hentaigana]

From right to left: すぎ、みな、、すゝ（すず）